# How to understand "trusting relationships between actors of regulatory regimes"

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Fonseca, 2021](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/rego.12413?casa_token=pUsUKV0eVQ4AAAAA%3ABrKMq5SxohiHzBbRxwBwVqR1p-UnC5018gfnK4lWrFSWhYXJVu8Tzy69T9qT7CC0HBkFt6R5WhYSZeaF) states that

> On other side of the argument, how do we bring a global health
> approach to vaccine regulation? Cooperation among well-resourced
> regulatory authorities has been discussed by the FDA (National
> Academies of Sciences Engineering and Medicine 2019), but there are
> many challenges because of institutional legacies, technical, and
> financial resources, and areas of expertise. At the center of the
> problem is lack of trust (Benish & Levi-Faur 2020). Collaboration
> during crisis management will require **trusting relationships between
> actors of regulatory regimes**. There is an increasing interest in the
> study of trust relationships within regulatory regimes; for instance,
> the Trust in Governance and Regulation in Europe (TiGRE),2 a European
> Union Horizon 2020 initiative, which brings together leading scholars
> in the field of regulation and is well-equipped to investigate these
> questions.

I understand that actors of regulatory regimes are polices, military,... but I do not understand what does "**trusting relationships between actors of regulatory regimes**" mean. Is there any example to explain this phrase?

Comment: **actors of regulatory regimes** is not idiomatic writing. The authors are using **regimes** in a non-standard manner as a synonym for "governmental agency" or "governmental regulatory body", for the "regulatory authorities" mentioned earlier.  Perhaps the lead author was translating a term from the Portuguese and we have a  so-called "false friend" mistranslation situation?

Comment: It seems to be jargon used in the public health sphere for "organization" or "system" See p 25 here: https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Rise_of_Global_Health/RvOZBgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=regime+agency+public+health&pg=PA25&printsec=frontcover

Comment: And here https://muse.jhu.edu/article/394856/pdf

Comment: This is not a translation and regulatory regimes is right. It means regulatory bodies or structures.

Answer (score 0):

The regulatory bodies have to be willing to trust each other and cooperate in order to make progress. Sometimes agencies that were intended to work together actually end up competing with each other (sometimes called in-fighting), but if that happens here, they are not going to accomplish anything.

Answer (score 0):

2. COUNTABLE NOUN
   A regime is the way that something such as an institution, company, or economy is run, especially when it involves tough or severe action.
   The authorities moved him to the less rigid regime of an open prison.

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/regime)

actors of regulatory regimes means those in structures or bodies or institutions regulating vaccination policy.